# How to install Docker and Postgres on AL2023

Tags: postgresql, docker, amazon-web-services

What I want to do:

> Install Docker and use a Postgres image to create a database to use with a Nest.js tut

What i have tried:

I have installed docker using:

`yum install docker`

Which yields when I do `docker --version`:

`Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701`

But when I try  `systemctl start docker.service` I get:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
> Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

I remember using installing docker on a mac and it was a cinch

Is it really this hard to install just because of AL2023?

Comment: What's "AL2023"? How do you interpret the error message? What does a `systemd` error have to do with database administration?

Comment: It means Amazon Linux, 2023. Someone told me on stack overflow to come post this question here as it has to do with databases.

Comment: It doesn't appear to have much to do with databases; it is about running Docker on Amazon Linux. Once you figure that one out and have some trouble with Postgres, then this site will be more appropriate.

Comment: Well, I respectfully disagree because those commands should work out of the box and they don’t.

Comment: That's fine, but please consider this: The chances of somebody knowing how to diagnose the `systemd` problem with Amazon Linux on this site, where people discuss database normalisation and query execution plans, are notably lower than, say, on a [Linux-related site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or talking to the Amazon technical support.

Comment: And, oh, by the way: it's "Postgres" or "PostgreSQL", not "Postgress".